# How do I lower ebs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I've only just starting using ecs and it seems like ebs is sky rocking.**I wanna stay within the free tier without worrying about this**  
 
**My question is how do i lower ebs?**

[image]

I'm using terraform ecs module. ***I changed the root_block_device_size to 10***

```
module "ecs_cluster" {
  cluster_instance_root_block_device_size = 10

}
```

This is the library I'm using [Ecs module link(Terraform)](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/infrablocks/ecs-cluster/aws/latest?tab=inputs)

It mentions this

```
cluster_instance_root_block_device_size number
Description: The size in GB of the root block device on cluster instances.
Default: 30

cluster_instance_root_block_device_type string
Description: The type of the root block device on cluster instances ('standard', 'gp2', or 'io1').
Default: "standard"
```

**For my ecs i have changed the block device size to 10 not sure if i should mess around with gp2 or io1 to lower it**

Thanks!

**Update** using this https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/ and by
putting my configuration and **it seems like gp3 and lowering the gigabytes does lower the price**....**However** it seems like doing 10gb cannot be initialized with Terraform so i started deploying it with 30gb and lowered it to 10gb and it seemed to have worked...

Answer (score 1):

That screenshot is for I/Os. Those are reads/writes to the disk volume(s). That's not related to the size of the volumes. Changing it from `30GB` to `10GB` is not going to impact the I/Os metric at all.

I/Os are only charged on magnetic EBS volume types. If you switched to an SSD based EBS volume type, like gp2, you would not be charged for the I/Os.

The AWS Free Tier includes "30 GB of Amazon EBS: any combination of General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic". So you could have up to 30GB of free gp2 volumes, which would be **much** faster than the standard magnetic volumes you are using now, and you would also not be charged for I/Os on those volumes.

Comment: ahh cool so all i do is ``` module "ecs_cluster" {
  cluster_instance_root_block_device_size = 30
 cluster_instance_root_block_device_type = "gp2"
}``` and it should be all good ? it default to standard not sure what "standard" is but hey thanks!